# using bower for cq5 (how to realize the livereload in CQ5?)

Tags: gruntjs, npm, bower, aem

I have followed this tutorial about YEOMAN for frontend development. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gKiaLSJW5xI . The livereload feature is very interesting. When you change anything in some js, css or html file, the browser is automatically reloaded and you can see the changes.

My Question is, how to integrate this feature for cq5? I would like when I have changed anything in some js, css or html file, that the page is atomatically reloaded and I can see these changes. I hope somebody already did it and can hepl me.

Answer (score 0):

There's an implementation of LiveReload for AEM here: http://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-tools/features/live-reload.html

Comment: No. It requires at least 5.6 and only works fully with 6.0 due to some changes in the client library system (which were introduced in part to support this project).